# How to create a generic extension method for async methods?

Tags: c#, async-await, task, extension-methods

I am trying to create a `.WithDelay(seconds);` method which I can add at the end of async method calls.

The issue I get is the async method is called first then the delay happens, I want it the other way around, without switching the order of the call.

For example, I want `await MyMethod().WithDelay(seconds);` rather than `await WithDelay(seconds).MyMethod();`.

Here is what I have so far, it calls the method first:

```
public async static Task<T> WithDelay<T>(this Task<T> task, int delay) {
  await Task.Delay(delay);
  return await task;
}
```

I expect the delay to happen first, then the actual method to run.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> I want it the other way around, without switching the order of the call.

This isn't possible, because the C# language only supports extension methods on *types*, not *methods*.

The closest you can get is an extension method on delegates:

```
public static async Task<T> WithDelay<T>(this Func<Task<T>> func, int delay) {
  await Task.Delay(delay);
  return await func();
}
```

The usage still ends up being awkward:

```
// Either:
Func<Task<MyType>> func = MyMethod;
var result = await func.WithDelay(1000);

// or (assuming "using static"):
var result = await WithDelay(MyMethod, 1000);

// What you really want, not currently possible:
// var result = await MyMethod.WithDelay(1000);
```

For type-related situations like this, it can help to solve the problem synchronously first, then convert that solution to `async`. If the language prevents a good synchronous solution, then it will likely prevent a good asynchronous solution.

There is a [proposal](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/16105) for extension methods on methods, but it's not part of the language today.

Comment: Not the answer I was looking for, but thank you. I'll give up looking.

Answer (score -1):

Would below work?

```
public static Task Async<T>(this T o, Action<T> action, CancellationToken token = default) {
  if (token.IsCancellationRequested) {
    return Task.FromCanceled(token);
  }
  try {
    action(o);
    return Task.CompletedTask;
  } catch (Exception e) {
  return Task.FromException(e);
  }
}
```

Example:

```
public static Task CommitAsync(this IDbTransaction transaction, CancellationToken token = default) 
  => transaction.Async(x=> transaction.Commit(), token);
```